DataNucleus Enhancer: 'The Command Line is Too Long' Error on Windows
I am working on a project using DataNucleus and encountering an issue when running the command mvn datanucleus:enhance on Windows. The command works fine on Linux and Mac, but on Windows, I get the following error:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR]  Standard error from the DataNucleus tool + org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR] The command line is too long.
[ERROR] --------------------

It seems that the command line length exceeds the limit imposed by Windows.
And here is the plugin configuration in the pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <api>JPA</api>
        <persistenceUnitName>${env.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME:h2}</persistenceUnitName>
        <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

Here is the relevant part of my persistence.xml:
<persistence-unit name="h2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.mycompany.core.user.model.User</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.core.subscription.model.Subscription</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.core.project.model.Project</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.core.collaborator.model.Collaborator</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.core.domain.model.Domain</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.connectionPoolingType" value="None"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.schema.validateAll" value="false"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.metadata.validate" value="false"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.log.level" value="DEBUG"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

Environment:

Windows (Error occurs)
Linux/Mac (Works fine)

What could be causing this issue on Windows, and what are some potential workarounds to address the command line length limitation?

You need to look at the actual command that's being passed through, which you'll probably need to do by using `mvn -X ...

Also where is the error coming from? Is an OS limit or a validation in some class? man -X may be helpful to find out

The solution is to add <fork>false</fork> into the configuration.
Here:
<configuration>
    <api>JPA</api>
    <persistenceUnitName>${env.PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME:h2}</persistenceUnitName>
    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <!-- Fix for command line too long error in Windows -->
    <fork>false</fork>
</configuration>

